# Proof of digital document integrity

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

Let's say we have the following scenario.

We have user A and user B and an initial digital document D generated by B. 
What algorithms and infrastructure are required in order to guarantee/prove that neither A or B have changed the initial document D? Can this be done without involving a third party authority?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)** "If your question... is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: This is not even a homework. This is a question related to a specific requirement. How did you assume that I am a student?

Comment: Both A and B provide their digital signature on the document. If either of them changes the document, the the other's signature will not match.

Comment: I think you should take this to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Read up on digital signatures and message digests.  This is a good start: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5646/1909

Comment: See also https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x215.html

Comment: Thank you all for your time, comments and very useful links!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a solution. This can be done via a [`blockchain`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain). This is how parties that do not trust each other can agree.

This would be a very basic workflow.

First, both users would hash the document. Assuming they [agree on a hashing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) and they both trust the hashing algorithm, they now have the fingerprint of the file. The trust issue that arises from this prerequisite can also be solved via blockchain.

Assuming they have agreed on the hash of the document, they must now store this hash. Since we are talking about a hash, which is small, it can be written directly to the blockchain.

The question now arrises, what blockchain should they write this hash to?

They can't simply set up their own network, because [they are only two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem). Blockchain doesn't work for two parties, it needs at least three parties on the network.

However, that is not a problem. You can write it to the biggest blockchain in existence, the bitcoin blockchain.

If you want the challenge, look at [bitcore](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib) and write them a cli that writes a given message to the blockchain. Otherwise, Alice and Bob can just use [a service that writes stuff for you on the bitcoin blockchain](https://eternitywall.it/)

In this way, there will remain a permanent record of the documents fingerprint, distributed across all bitcoin nodes. Trust can be established by hashing the document again and checking against the existing record.

Comment: This answer is generally correct (+1), but now the collective block chain users have become a kind of third party in this trust model. Also, user A could create a changed document, then claim that the recorded hash on the blockchain is fake planted there by B or that they never agreed to such a scheme. [Non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) crypto schemes without trusted third parties are _difficult_.